# stand alone object code in C and inline functions

Tags: c, c11

I was reading about `inline` functions from [Inline Functions In C](https://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html) when I came across this line:

> Sometimes it is necessary for the compiler to emit a stand-alone copy of the object code for a function even though it is an inline function - for instance if it is necessary to take the address of the function, or if it can't be inlined in some particular context, or (perhaps) if optimization has been turned off. (And of course, if you use a compiler that doesn't understand inline, you'll need a stand-alone copy of the object code so that all the calls actually work at all.)

I am completely clueless about what it is trying to say, can somebody please explain it specially what is a **stand-alone object code**?

Comment: It says that the function might need to be compiled as a callable function and not to be inlined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Object code" generally refers to the output from the compiler handed over to the linker, as a middle step before machine code is generated.

What the text says is that if you for some reason take the address of the function, by for example using a function pointer to it, then the function can't be inlined. Because inlined functions don't have an address that can be called upon through a function pointer. Inline functions are just linked in together with the calling code without any function call actually being made.

Comment: Any example where the compiler generates an inline version as well as a stand alone code of a function?

Answer (score 3):

As you know, an "inline" function is translated to machine-instructions that are "right there."  Every time a new "call" to the function appears, those instructions are repeated verbatim in every different place -- the function is not actually "called."  (An inline function is very much like an assembler "macro.")

But, if you ask for (say) "the address of" the function, the compiler has to generate a non-inlined copy of it in order to be able to give you *one* "place where it is."

Comment: it can generate both

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int mul16(int x) {
    return x * 16; }

extern inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int mul3(int x) {
    return x * 3; }

int main() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        int (*ptr)(int) = rand() & 1 ? mul16 : mul3;
        printf("Mul2 = %d", mul16(i));
        printf(", ptr(i) = %d\n", ptr(i));
    } 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/wDpF4j

`mul16` exists as a separate object and is also inlined in the same code.

```
mul16:   <----- object
        mov     eax, edi
        sal     eax, 4
        ret
mul3:
        lea     eax, [rdi+rdi*2]
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "Mul2 = %d"
.LC1:
        .string ", ptr(i) = %d\n"
main:
        push    r12
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, 0
        mov     r12d, OFFSET FLAT:mul16
.L5:
        call    rand
        test    al, 1
        mov     ebp, OFFSET FLAT:mul3
        cmovne  rbp, r12
        mov     esi, ebx
        sal     esi, 4            <-------------- inlined version
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     edi, ebx
        call    rbp
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        add     ebx, 1
        cmp     ebx, 10
        jne     .L5
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
```